# MVC asp.net Resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC. I have added one controller and view and set route to view my index page. But it is giving me following error.

```
                 The resource cannot be found.
                 Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or 
                 one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its 
                 name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review 
                 the following URL and make sure that it is spelled 
                 correctly. 

         Requested URL: /
```

Comment: If you set a route, then please show us your route configuration and the related controller

Comment: public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: controller is        public class Home1Controller : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home1/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }

Comment: and add the URL you are trying to access

Comment: http://localhost:51897/HomeController/Index

Comment: Please, do us a favor and edit your question by adding the information.

Comment: You do not have a controller named `HomeController` - the one in your comments is `Home1Controller`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments I take it, that you misunderstood how the basics of MVC work. (You can read it all here: https://www.asp.net/mvc)

By default MVC has a lot of conventions, so it knows how a route maps to a controller amongst other things. When you issue a request to an url, the default implementation of the MvcHandler receives a controller instance from the default ControllerFactory implementation, which has a convention, that a controller must end on the name `Controller`. That means, that `/Home1Controller/` in your example, lets the controller factory look for a controller class named `Home1ControllerController`, which most likely does not exist.

For completeness, here are the criteria by which thew default controller factory identifies the correct controller:

- class scope must be public
- class must not be abstract
- class must not take generic parameters
- **class name must end on "Controller"**
- class must implement `IController` interface.

So if you keep the default route, which you have and you have created a controller called `Home1Controller`, then the route on which you can access the Index method is: `/Home1/Index`.

If your controller would be namend `FooController`, then the url would be `/Foo/`